# Wordpress Create a User Based Countdown Timer via PHP/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, countdown, countdowntimer

My question is about a current programming task I am sitting on. I want to program a countdown timer based on user creation.

So, for example, 'TestUser' wants to create an account today at 14:30. A timer is set on a specific page, which expires in 24 hours after registration. Therefore, it will expire on the 27th at 14:30. So, basically, a timer is set based on user data. To set the countdown timer always based on user data.

Hope you understood my question. I am really sitting on the issue for days so far. I thought it must be possible maybe via PHP/javascript since the Userdata is kept out from the backend as the server time and time data.

Do you know how to eventually solve this problem or hints to solve it or more if there already exists solution about that?

I am really looking forward to possible solutions.

Thank you so much,

*Aron*

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are looking for... do you want the account to expire after 24 hours?  Or the page to expire?  Or content on the page?  Can you try to be more clear on what exactly you are looking for?  Also, can you provide any sample code you might have tried so far...

Comment: What have you tried so far, if your are struggling with it? What purpose has your task? What happenes after 24 hours? If the expiration is a "hard time span" from creation time plus 24 hours: why not store creation timestamp in database. Then check for the user if he comes back, if 24 hours are expired?

Comment: You need to use the user system time for the timer? can you please provide more detail? you are not very much clear...

Comment: Sure, it should be if the User is registered at 14:30GMT 27th of July 2017 for example, then a countdown timer should be set for the date 14:30GMT 28th of July 2017 (so for 24 hours based on the registration date). I want the user to let him see the countdown timer. After the countdown ends, nothing should happen. So, it basically should only show a timer that ticks down based on the time the user register plus 24 hours. I was thinking to get the date via PHP when the user is registered and then via a custom function this time plus X-amount of time (24 hours in this case).

Comment: ...Then a countdown occurs via a visible timer for the user. I hope I could explain this better and more precious now. Thanks for your questions